# Вставка данных из JSON в bot.send_message

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, python-telegram-bot

У меня есть JSON который я разбираю и получаю нужные мне данные

```
data = response.json()
   for d in data:
        adress = d['adress']
        starttime = d['starttime']
```

Как мне эти данные вставить в bot.send_message?
Текст можно вставить так

```
bot.send_message(c.message.chat.id, 'Текст')
```

Но как вместо `'Текст'` вставить `adress = d['adress']` и `starttime = d['starttime']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
data = response.json()
   for d in data:
        adress = d['adress']
        starttime = d['starttime']

text = f"Address: {adress}\n Starttime: {starttime}"

bot.send_message(c.message.chat.id, text)
```

Comment: Не за что. То, что Вы хотите реализовать, можно сделать с помощью метода bot.edit_message_text(). В официальной документации есть много примеров, попробуйте, если не получится - создайте новый вопрос отдельно :)